# passing parameter but unable to fetch?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

how to resolve this one, unable to fetch ?
  I am passing the IN parameter but still unable to fetch.

```
 create or replace procedure p1(p_ename in varchar2,p_sal out number)is
 begin
  select salary into p_sal from employees where last_name=p_ename;
 dbms_output.put_line(p_sal);
 end;

 variable b number;
 execute p1('King',:b);


[info](https://infoallsite.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/unable-to-fetch- data)


 [error][1]

 ' got error ,but only one row has last_name as King, '
  how to resolve I  want  to get the salary of king.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsOHG.png'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You table probably has more than 1 rows for name `King`.

Run this

```
select count(*) from employees where last_name='King';
```

If it returns more than 1 row, then you have to choose which row do you need to select. If you want any row at random, then use this select in your procedure.

```
select salary into p_sal from employees 
where last_name=p_ename 
and rownum<2;
```

Comment: If it works for you, then accept the answer by clicking on tick symbol on left of the answer, so it could be closed. Thanks